# Ubuntu Trusty always errors out when running apt-get install/update/upgrade

Tags: 14.04

I first noticed this when I was installing docker, but realised that it's coming from even simple installations.

Output from my `sudo apt-get install update-manager`

```
...
....
aspell-au

Blockquote

tobuildhash: processing: en [en_CA-variant_1]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_CA-w_accents-only]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_CA-wo_accents-only]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_GB-ise-w_accents-only]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_GB-ise-wo_accents-only]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_GB-ize-w_accents-only]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_GB-ize-wo_accents-only]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_GB-variant_0]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_GB-variant_1]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_US-w_accents-only]
aspell-autobuildhash: processing: en [en_US-wo_accents-only]
Setting up hunspell-en-us (20070829-4ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libenchant1c2a:amd64 (1.6.0-10ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up enchant (1.6.0-10ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-webkit-3.0 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up aspell (0.60.7~20110707-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.20.5) ...
Setting up aspell-en (7.1-0-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up ubuntu-drivers-common (1:0.2.91.12) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up software-properties-gtk (0.92.37.8) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:0.220.9) ...
Setting up update-notifier (0.154.1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up update-manager (1:0.196.24) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.13) ...
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.20.5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scx
```

My Ubuntu is Trusty - output of `lsb_release -a`

```
root@xxx:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I am not a typical Linux/UNIX user, but it seems to me that there is a bug in the kernel somewhere. Does anyone have a clue?